# Android change popup menu text color

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've tried many things to change the text color when i click the "three dot" menu button but it always reverts back to the toolbar (android:theme) theme and not the android:popupTheme. I want the text to be black but it always shows up white.

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
<style name="MaterialWorkout_theme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#48FFFFFF</item>
</style>
<style name="Popup_theme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#38000000</item>
</style>
```

app_bar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primaryColor"
android:id="@+id/app_bar"
android:theme="@style/MaterialWorkout_theme"
android:popupTheme="@style/Popup_theme"
>
```

Here is what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEiiN.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. changed my toolbar.xml file to this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/primaryColor"
android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
android:theme="@style/MaterialWorkout_theme"
app:popupTheme="@style/Popup_theme">
```

notice the implementation of:

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

and

app:popupTheme="@style/Popup_theme"

these two lines solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Use below code .I hope this will solve your problem.You can change both background color and textcolor.

```
 <style name="AppFullScreenThemeNight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <!-- if using android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu -->
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>


<style name="PopupMenu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/button_color</item> 
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your popup menu theme in your style, not you Toolbar.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Popup_theme</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you! But that still didn't work. I also tried implementing different styles and even android:actionMenuTextColor and it still did not work